# Checking if a button exists in java

Tags: java, netbeans

I have some radio buttons and each one of then create a button with the Name "OK", such button is meant to proceed.
However, I need to check if the button already exists so the program don't create a copy of the button each time one of the radio buttons is clicked.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you create the "OK" button along with the radiobuttons? Then you could activate and deactivate as if needed...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: because when the user clicks if the "Custom" radio button, the program will add some text filds and the Ok button would be located before the textsfields, what I dont want to hapen, The OK button should always be the last thing shown on the window

Comment: *"because when the user clicks if the "Custom" radio button, the program will add some text filds"* this fiels moer like a TabbedPane-solution... - *"and the Ok button would be located before the textsfields,"* You could place the Button in The `SOUTH` area of a GridLayout and the TextFields in a separate Panel in the GridLayouts `CENTER`.

Comment: @ViníciusGabriel could you share source code?

Comment: I followed the the tip of Timothy and it worked, so I do need to check if the button exists anymore. But I'll be grateful if someone show me how to do this in case I still needed it.

Answer (score 0):

Check by the variable name. It won't allow you to create a variable with the same name...